# Using onSavedInstance for other classes than pregiven methods

Tags: android

How add in items inside my onSavedInstance such as a completely different class such as a hashmap with multiple items inside it.

How would we be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashMap` implements `Serializable`, so as long as both your key and value types are also serializable, you can put your entire map in the Bundle.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I was thinking bundle because it seemed like the perfect word for multiple items.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) object in the bundle:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable(java.lang.String, java.io.Serializable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29)